# Intermittent memory error on DRF serializer.save and large data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have some django-rest-framework code where it receives some fairly large data under a POST request. The large data comes in the form of a String (models.TextField() in the relevant model) around 37MB or so.

When it gets to serializer.save(), I typically get (not always) memory errors once DRF reaches about 300MB of memory usage.

Is there a way of minimising memory usage with Django-Rest when uploading large data (the string does not cleanly split up, and ideally I could store it in the Postgres DB).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [`FileField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#file-upload-fields) and the [`FileUploadParser`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser)? [`CharField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) (which DRF renders `models.TextFields()` as) are not well suited to large amounts of data like that.